# Accessing windows server deduplicated files from other operating systems

Tags: windows-server-2012, deduplication

If you enable data deduplication on the Windows Server 2012, it will change certain files (according to the policy) and introduce reparse points.

If the drive containing deduplicated volumes is detached from Windows Server 2012 and attached to another system with another operating system (like Windows 8) the volume is readable, but the files included in the deduplication policy can not be accessed or copied.

One way is to un-optimize the volume using `Start-DedupJob -Type Unoptimization` powershell command, but my question is, is there a way to make these files accessible in the optimized form at least in Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can actually install dedup in windows 8.0 or 8.1

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/34417-Data-deduplication-for-Windows-8-x64

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is not.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2012/05/21/introduction-to-data-deduplication-in-windows-server-2012.aspx

> 3) Portability: A volume that is under deduplication control is an
>   atomic unit. You can back up the volume and restore it to another
>   server. You can rip it out of one Windows 2012 server and move it to
>   another. Everything that is required to access your data is located on
>   the drive. All of the deduplication settings are maintained on the
>   volume and will be picked up by the deduplication filter when the
>   volume is mounted. The only thing that is not retained on the volume
>   are the schedule settings that are part of the task-scheduler engine.
>   If you move the volume to a server that is not running the Data
>   Deduplication feature, you will only be able to access the files that
>   have not been deduplicated.